# Modify the destination for the response

Tags: botframework

I use Microsoft Bot Framework. From: https://dev.botframework.com/
AND
Microsoft Bot Emulator (V4 Preview) version 4.0.15-alpha. From: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-emulator

I created a new C# project with "Bot Application" template. I run this project. I launched two entities of the Emulator. 
Now I receive the message from the first Emulator entity but I want to send the response to the second Emulator entity. How can I do this?

This is the function where I try to modify the destination (the code that is commented) but does not work.

```
/// <summary>
/// POST: api/Messages
/// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
/// </summary>
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    //activity.Recipient.Id = "default-user";
    //activity.ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:52234";
    //activity.Conversation.Id = "e7bbb310-a93c-11e8-8dcc-7d6fd69e3901|livechat";
    //activity.ReplyToId = "6cc291f0-a93d-11e8-9634-9f01a6c082d4";

    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking.  What specific emulator framework are you discussing?  You have tagged [tag:bots] which is very generic.  Please also add any supporting code that would help us understand your problem further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I launched two entities of the Emulator. Now I receive the message from the first Emulator entity but I want to send the response to the second Emulator entity. How can I do this?

Before you write code to send message to another emulator, you need to get the value of `ServiceUrl` and `conversationId` etc. And then you could refer to the following code to send message to the specified conversation.

*In dialog:*

```
await context.PostAsync($"{this.count++}: You said {activity.Text}");

var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "User", id: "default-user");
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Bot", id: "default-bot");

var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("{your_ServiceUrl_here}"));

IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;

//specify conversationId
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "{your_conversationId_here}");
message.Text = $"You said {activity.Text} from emulator1";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

*Test result:*

[image]